# If $f(z)$ is a polynomial function of degree $n \ge 2$, prove that the sum of the residues of $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is zero

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, residue-calculus

Let $f(z)=a_nz^n +a_{n-1} z^{n-1} +...+a_1z+a_0$ be a polynomial of degree $n \ge 2$. Prove that the sum of the residues of $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is zero.

Ok, so here is my thinking process so far: At first I had no clue what to do, but then I thought about the fact that this is a polynomial, which is analytic throughout and if that is so, then the residue is 0. But this seemed too simple. Taking $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ into consideration, I knew that there had to be some singularities, if nothing else, 0. Then i got stuck again. Im thinking that it has something to do with the deformation of paths??

Further: Textbook definition gives me something like this     $\,\,\,\,\int_{C_2} \frac{dz}{f(z)}  + \int_{-C_2} \frac{dz}{f(z)} =0$

And since C is a positively oriented simple closed contour with center at the origin, with $z_0$ entirely inside, then $\int_C \frac{dz}{f(z)}=2\pi i$ and since $\frac{dz}{f(z)}$ is analytic everywhere except at $z=0$, then the sum of the integrals equals 0.

Comment: "Im thinking that it has something to do with the deformation of paths??" Yes, it does. Can you write the sum of the residues as an integral?

Comment: Hint: Integrate over a huge circle.

Comment: Haha, or in order to do it directly, use Lagrange's Interpolation.

Answer (score 3):

If the degree of our polynomial $f(x)$ is greater than $1$, we have:
$$ f(x) \gg |x|^2 $$
as long as $|x|\to +\infty$. This gives:
$$\frac{1}{f(x)}\ll\frac{1}{|x|^2},$$
so the integral of $f(x)$ over the set $\{x:|x|=R\}$ is $O\left(\frac{1}{R}\right)$.

Now we just need to apply the Residue theorem and consider the limit as $R\to +\infty$.

Comment: DAurizio, I'm a little confused by your notation, what do you mean by $is O (\frac{1}{R}$. Are you referring to the center of the cirlce or the radius?

Comment: @cele: it is the Landau notation. We say that $f(x)=O(g(x))$ for $x\to +\infty$ if there exists some constant $C$ such that $|f(x)|\leq C\cdot |g(x)|$ for any $x$ big enough. We just need to prove that the integral of $f(z)$ over the set $\{x:|x|=R\}$ converges to zero as $R$ tends to $+\infty$.